# Elasticsearch polygonize TIFF map

Tags: gdal, geojson, geotiff-tiff, elasticsearch

I am having an heavy TIFF map around 2Go and I want to index it in ES in order to geolocate data of this file. With GDAL, I could polygonize only a part of it in GeoJSON, but seems that big polygons are not handled.
Do you know a better way to upload a map and its data into Elasticsearch?

Comment: GDAL should be able to build big polygons as well as small ones. Could you offer test data? However, polygonizing large rasters is heavy work and it could be better to split the source raster.

Comment: I dont know how to split the source. I would be very pratical to study a part of the map and see what's missing too.
For now, I have a 1G0 Tiff and a 5.6Go GeoJson file to share. will it help you?

Comment: Gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html has -srcwin and -projwin options for selecting subsets from images.